# Optimizing database update

Tags: mysql, laravel, optimization, laravel-5

I have to update really large set of data, and so far I have this:

```
protected function updateWidgetsDb($APIWidgets, $date)
{
    echo "Eager loading...";
    $widgets = Widget::where('date', $date)->get();
    echo "Done\n";
    echo "Updating...";
    foreach ($APIWidgets as $APIWidget) {
        $widget = $widgets->where('widget_id', $APIWidget->dimensions[0])->first();

        if ($widget == null)
            continue;

        $widget->update(['revenue' => $APIWidget->metrics[0]->values[0]]);
    }
    echo "Done\n";
}
```

`$APIWidgets` is an array which is fetched through external API. I am fetching data only for a specific date so I am loading only data from that date which already exists in the DB.

`widget_id` field is indexed in DB

**EDIT:**

I have about 60k of data with about 2k data I am receiving for update. Each record of those 2k has an ID which can already be found in existing 60k data. So after update, the sum of data should still be 60k, not 62k.

Currently, update process takes ~10 minutes.

Comment: What is the size of an updating set? Why do you use `get()` in the second line?

Comment: `$widgets` is eloquent collection, and later on he uses [where() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-where)

Comment: @Norgul can you provide more information? How many elements does `$APIWidgets` have?

Comment: Depending on API call, but lets say 2k

Comment: and how many elements in `$widgets` do you have?

Comment: About 60k per day (I'm aiming to have 7 day data, so complete DB about half a million records)

Comment: So you need to update 2k entries (only `first` ones) out of 60k fetched (~30 entries per one `widget_id`), right? How much time does it take now, when you use 2k update queries?

Comment: @Norgul you should update the question with the info that you provided in the comments

Comment: Why does your `Widget` model have `widget_id` property as if it is a child of a widget? Is it just an `id` maybe?

Comment: What values can be in `revenue` property? Something that can be grouped (say, it can be only 1,2 and 3 only) or that can not (34.23, 44.23 etc.)?

Comment: It is an ID, normal `id` is just autoincrement

Comment: Do `widget_id` and `date` form a unique pair that unambiguously determine a record in the database? All the key points should be cleared in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose two methods to speed up a mass update task. I tried to reproduce your issue, so I created a set of 60k*7 items at my `widgets` table with `widget_id,date` and `widget_id` indexes.

1. First let's make getting `$widget` faster. When I replaced `$widgets->where('widget_id', $APIWidget->id)` with

   ```
   Widget::where('date', $date)
      ->where('widget_id', $APIWidget->id)
   ```

   the script became ~400x times faster. Looks like 2000 mysql fetching using index `widget_id, date` is faster, than Laravel collection search through 60000-size collection. My results was 16 seconds for queries and ~6400 seconds for collections.
2. Then let's make update faster. There is a nice approach to update table with only one query using temporary table. So I created a new entity `WidgetUpdate` with table `widget_updates` and fields `id, widget_id, revenue_new`.

   I've modified your method: first I collect an array of updates, then
   I make a bulk insert into `widget_updates` table and after all I
   perform a single updating query. My machine does it for 2.2 seconds,
   5x times faster. The final speedup is 2000x for my case.

   ```
   protected function updateWidgetsDb($APIWidgets, $date)
   {
     echo "Updating...";
     $updates = [];

     foreach ($APIWidgets as $APIWidget) {
       $widget = Widget::where('date', $date)
           ->where('widget_id', $APIWidget->dimensions[0])
           ->first();

       if ($widget == null)
           continue;

       $updates[] = ['revenue_new' => $APIWidget->metrics[0]->values[0]];
     }

     # inserting and updating
     WidgetUpdate::insert($updates);
     DB::statement('UPDATE widgets, widget_updates ' . 
               'SET widgets.revenue=widget_updates.revenue_new '.
               'WHERE widgets.id = widget_updates.widget_id');

     echo "Done\n";
   }
   ```

Don't forget to cleanup temp table on finish.

Comment: Can you explain, why did you get 600 seconds for a set of the same size as mine?